# sms gateway with url callback option

Tags: sms

I know there are a bunch of SMS gateway related questions on this site but i have a specific requirement that i would like some direction on.

For example:

> Lets say i wanted to create an SMS activated emailing application. A user might send the following message to the SMS gateway:
>
> 'me@email.com : hey, ill be home late for dinner'
>
> And the gateway would receive the SMS and post to 'myapp.com/email/create' with the various details of the SMS in the post data.

Can anybody recommend an SMS gateway (needs to be used with Australian number) that has the ability to post the message etc to my own website when a user sends an SMS to the gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all of them.

- [Clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/)
- [SMS Global](http://www.smsglobal.com/)
- [Message Media](http://www.message-media.com.au/)
- [Informatel](http://www.informatel.com/) (Probably, I haven't integrated with these guys specifically, but I'm certain they can)

They all do this (you configure the URL).

-- Edit: Just incase it's not obvious, you need to have a dedicated number for this purpose. If you don't, they use a general (and sometimes rotating) number for sending your messages out. Obviously, if you wish to have a message go directly to you (2-way service, is what they call it) you need to have a dedicated number.

Comment: clicktell seems to only send a message status report to your callback url and i cant find documentation that suggests message media supports this requirement

Comment: also, sms global seem to only offer the ability to call a url on a message reply, which isnt quite what im after. I need the originating message that is sent to a gateway to be posted to my url.

Comment: They all do it; you set a return URL, and when a message comes in to that number (initiated by you or not) it will hit your URL. With SMS Global, and Clickatell you can set it in the interface (sign up, it's free IIRC, and you can check it out). With Message Media, I can't remember, but it was definitely possible (I did it).

Comment: i know they can hit a specified url, the problem is i need the original message forwared to a url, not just a status report.

Comment: meboz: You are not listening to what I am saying. How can I make it clear to you? *They let you configure that*. I will leave you to accept this realisation in your own time. Good luck.

Comment: given that i have accounts for both clickatell and sms global and have trawled through both their docs and sent a number of test messages, i dont believe they satisfy the requirements.

Are you able to point to some documentation to suggest otherwise?

Comment: In the SMS Global console, when you have a dedicated number (see my edit, perhaps this is where your confusion lies), you can set the HTTP 2-way URL. Same with Clickatell.

Comment: indeed, having a dedicated number was NOT obvious. this is a prereq of my requirement.

Here is the docs for clickatell - http://www.clickatell.com/downloads/Clickatell_two-way_technical_guide.pdf

Comment: meboz: Apologies for not being clear on that, it did slip my mind.